# Efficient and maintainable query to compare derived data over time

Tags: mysql, sql

I've a database containing ScanSessions and LapEntries.

```
CREATE TABLE `ScanningSession` (
     `id` varchar(512) NOT NULL,
     `startDate` datetime NOT NULL)

  CREATE TABLE `LapEntry` (
    `studentId` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `laps` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `scanSessionId` varchar(512) DEFAULT NULL,
    `timestamp` datetime DEFAULT NULL)
```

Entries are linked to Sessions by the Session ID, thus many-to-one.
I have a fairly large query that derives data at multiple levels.
 Since it has to derive lap times from start of session, lap splits, total time and things like ordinality(lap 1, lap 2) and total distance after each lap, its big

```
    select
  `le`.`studentId`,

  ifnull(
      (
        select TIMEDIFF(`le`.`timestamp`, max(`timestamp`))
        from `LapEntry` `le3`
        where `le3`.`studentId` = `le`.`studentId`
              and `le3`.`scanSessionId` = `ss`.`id`
              and `le3`.`timestamp` < `le`.`timestamp`
      ),
      timediff(`le`.`timestamp`, `ss`.`startDate`)
  )                             as `laptime`,
     `studentSessionOverview`.`dist`,
     `studentSessionOverview`.`numLaps`
from `ScanningSession` `ss`
  join `LapEntry` `le`
    on `le`.`scanSessionId` = `ss`.`id`

  join (
         select
           `studentId`,
           max(`timestamp`)    `max_timestamp`,
           count(*)            `numLaps`,
           (sum(`le2`.`laps`) * `c`.`distance` * `cu`.`convertToMiles`) / `su`.`convertToMiles` `dist`
         from `LapEntry` `le2`,
           `Course` `c`,
           `Unit` `cu`,
           `School` `s`,
           `Unit` `su`
         where `c`.`id` = `le2`.`courseId`
               and `cu`.`id` = `c`.`unitId`
               and `s`.`id` = 'school id here'
               and `su`.`id` = `s`.`defaultUnitId`
               and `le2`.`scanSessionId` ='sessionID here' 
         group by `studentId`
       ) as `studentSessionOverview`

    on `studentSessionOverview`.`studentId` = `le`.`studentId`
where `ss`.`id` = 'sessionID here';
```

My problem actually starts when I try to do comparisons between two scanning sessions. Users want to see a given student's progress between two sessions.

The problem is that as far as I can tell if I want to do this, I'm stuck using a join on two hard-copies of the code, so that the query is ~150 lines, most of it duplicated.

```
   select
  `a`.`firstNAme`,
  `a`.`lastName`,
  `a`.`laptime` - `b`.`laptime`     as `lapDifference`,
  `a`.`totalTime` - `b`.`totalTime` as `totalDifference`
  from (*wall of sql here*) as a
  join (*wall of sql here*) as b 
    on `a`.`studentId` = `b`.`studentId` and `a`.`lapOrder` = 
    `b`.`lapOrder`
```

Is there a way I can derive this data without hard-copying my query?
I can't see how to get all of the data needed for each session and then do session comparison on top of it all.

P.S. I did consider using stored procedures and running the procedure as a call from the parent query but that forces me to keep some SQL in my API code and some in the server on stored procedures, which is as bad a maintenance problem as what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: This is TL;DR in my opinion. Please provide a MVP and a succinct explanation of what you are looking to accomplish.

Comment: I've removed what I think I can lose without breaking context. The problem is that I've got like 3 layers of derived data and now I'm trying to do comparisons on that data, a fact I'm pretty sure I conveyed in the post.

The issue at hand is TL:DR, I don't know what can be removed given that the size of the query and the multiple layers of interacting data are the key to what I'm trying to figure out.

Comment: I've tried to strip it as much as possible but again, the problem is the length of what I'm doing, I don't know how to push that much more.

Comment: Having spent very little time looking at the detail all I can say is - looks like something best accomplished not in SQL. Probably more efficient to pull the data into the application and process it. SQL just isn't designed to be a multipurpose programming language.

Comment: You could use CTEs (available since MySQL 8.0) or a view for your "wall of SQL".

Comment: A possible solution I've been ruminating on is to basically compose the sql on my api as a string so that I can store the repeated component as a variable and thus avoid the conflict. I'll post it as an answer if it works out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this in my case ended up being to step back to my API code and compose this query as a string.

So something structured like this:

```
string subSql = *The large query with parameters*;
string sql = 'select * from (subSql, parameters for session 1) as A
join (subsql, parameters for session 2) as B 
on a.sessionId = b.sessionId;
```

Once I added the necessary derived values I was able to get a fast query to select the data.